# How to shuffle big JSON file?

Tags: python, json, random

I have a JSON file with 1 000 000 entries in it (Size: 405 Mb). It looks like that:

```
[
  {
     "orderkey": 1,
     "name": "John",
     "age": 23,
     "email": "john@example.com"
  },
  {
     "orderkey": 2,
     "name": "Mark",
     "age": 33,
     "email": "mark@example.com"
  },
...
]
```

The data is sorted by "orderkey", I need to shuffle data.

I tried to apply the following Python code. It worked for smaller JSON file, but did not work for my 405 MB one.

```
import json
import random

with open("sorted.json") as f:
     data = json.load(f)

random.shuffle(data)

with open("sorted.json") as f:
     json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

How to do it?

***UPDATE:***

Initially I got the following error:

```
~/Desktop/shuffleData$ python3 toShuffle.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrei/Desktop/shuffleData/toShuffle.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 403646259 (char 403646258)
```

Figured out that the problem was that I had "}" in the end of JSON file. I had `[{...},{...}]}` that was not valid.

Removing "}" fixed the problem.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did you get an error? Too long of a runtime? Unexpected results?

Comment: You should specify whether you are opening the file for reading or for writing. And don't write to the same file you are reading from.

Comment: The only problem with the *code* is the failure to open `sorted.json` for writing before using `json.dump`. Whether you have enough memory to store the entire contents in memory is another question.

Comment: is `orderkey` literally 1 to 1_000_000? Is the reason you want to sort the json so that you can process records in a random order?

Comment: If you don't have enough memory, the only solutions would be to buy more memory (which is not a programming issue) or to use a different library than `json` (recommendations for which are off-topic here) which could allow for an on-disk shuffle.

Comment: I don't think this code worked for a shorter JSON file.

Comment: @JonSG Yes, indeed, I want to process records in random order.

Comment: @JNevill Added details to the post, issue was in "}" in the end of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the problem was that I had "}" in the end of JSON file. I had `[{...},{...}]}` that was not valid format.

Removing "}" in the end fixed the problem.

Provided python code works.

Answer (score 0):

Well this should ideally work unless you have memory constraints.

```
import random
random.shuffle(data)
```

In case you are looking for another way and would like to benchmark which is faster for the huge set, you can use the sci-kit learn libraries shuffle function.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

shuffled_data = shuffle(data)
print(shuffled_data)
```

Note: Additional package has to be installed called Scikit learn. (`pip install -U scikit-learn`)

Comment: The sklearn shuffle implementation can be found here - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b13a8f120a6d67112b0f50a8834d65e2258f045/sklearn/utils/__init__.py#L617